# How can I receive an IPN Notification that I have sent a payment with PayPal - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an option on my website to allow the admin to send payment to users through PayPal, how can I make sure that the funds have left the admin's account? Is there an IPN notification for this? I am trying to update a field in my database to true once the payment has gone through.

Please note that I am using PayPal, Rails 4, Ruby 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: take a look on active merchant gem

Answer (score 0):

If your notification URL is set in your PayPal account profile, all payments, transaction reversals (such as chargebacks), refunds, subscription events and buyer disputes trigger an Instant Payment Notification.

For more information on Instant Payment Notification (IPN) and to view the manual, visit the PayPal website at: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Comment: I haven't found this to be true. Specifically, I issued two refunds for payments that I did get IPNs for, and the refunds still haven't shown up as IPNs a week later.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you issue a refund it will trigger an IPN message immediately. You would only get one IPN message.

Comment: it's hard to say without being able to reconstruct exactly what happened. If you call into support they can help you track down what occurred.

Comment: Hmm. I got a transaction without a `txn_type` that caused my IPN servlet to crash. Fixed that and now I am getting them. It appears `txn_type` is `null` for this transaction ...